# L'Hopital's rule conditions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, limits

I have seen easy geometrical argument why L'Hopital's rule ($\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$) works (local linearization). But, I *still* don't understand this:

1. why is rule defined just when limit is in form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\pm \frac{\infty}{\infty}$?
2. Why must be $f(a) = g(a) = 0$ ?
3. why must be $g'(a) \neq 0$?

Counterexample for 1: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x}{x^2 + x + 1} = \frac{1}{1}$ but is also $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^x)'}{(x^2 + x + 1)'} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x}{2x + 1} = \frac{1}{1}.$ So, L'Hopital's rule works here but $\frac{1}{1} \neq \frac{0}{0}$!

Also, I read that there is another condition:
4. $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ must exist

- does condition 3 implies this?
- can you give example when original limit exist but $\frac{f'}{g'}$ does not and how is this possible if functions $f, g$ are differentiable?

Comment: Just a note on your "counterexample" for 1: it is not a counterexample, because this rule does not apply to that case (in general). Your example only shows that sometimes the limits may be the same, but this is not true in general

Comment: Yes, it is not counterexample in general. I am interested in why this condition exist, logic behind it. $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^x)'}{(2x + 1)'} = \lim{x \to 0}\frac{e^x}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ (wrong result)

Comment: Regarding 4, I think you actually mean that the limit of the quotient of the derivatives must exist. Indeed, otherwise you would not be allowed to conclude anything by L'Hopital rule. 3 does not imply 4

Comment: Is one of your questions why we can't use L'Hopital's Rule when, say, we have a limit of the form $\frac11$?  If so, one seeming counterexample is $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{2-x} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$, but $\frac{(x)'}{(2-x)'} \to \frac{1}{-1} = -1$.

Comment: $Manuel Norman, can you give example for 4?

Comment: Your Rule $1$ is not accurate. If $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$, then the rule applies regardless of whether $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ even exists.

Comment: The intuitive basis behind that is that only when the numerator and denominator both go to $0$ (or to the point at infinity) do the relative slopes indicate the ratio of the vanishing (or expanding, respectively) quantities.

Comment: @1b3b we are interested in studying indeterminate forms. A limit for which we have $1/1=1$ is simple to evaluate (usually). The most interesting cases are when we have an indeterminate form, and L'Hopital rule is useful for the cases $0/0$ and $\infty/ \infty$.

Comment: As an example for 4: let $f(x)=x+\sin x$, $g(x)=3x$. The limit for $x \rightarrow \infty$ exists, but the limit of the quotient of derivative doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, all! This examples are very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily come up with counterexamples for applying L'Hôpital's rule when the limit is not of the form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$. For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{a}{1+a}\neq1=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1}{1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(x)'}{(1+x)'}.$$
The limit is never of the form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ and clearly L'Hôpital's rule does not work on this example. To see why the rule *does* work for limits of the $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ form, see any analysis textbook for a proof (for example, Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*).

We don't strictly need $g'(a)\neq0$. For example:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x^2+x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{2x+3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2}{2+6x}=1,$$
where we applied L'Hôpital's rule twice, but the second limit still is of the form $0/0$.

The limit $f'/g'$ may fail to exist even when the conditions for L'Hôpital's rule are satisfied and the limit $f/g$ exists; the classic example is:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+\sin(x)}{x}=1,$$
but upon applying L'Hôpital's rule we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}1+\cos(x),$$
for which the limit does not exist.

Comment: Suppose we have $f, g$ both differentiable on some interval $[a, b].$ We can approximate $f, g$ with lines (tangents) $t_f, t_g$ in interval $[a, a + dx]$ for small $dx > 0.$ If $f(a) \neq f(b)$ then intersection of $t_f, t_g$ is obviously not at the $x = a.$ WLOG suppose lines are not parallel; let $x_f \neq x_g$ be their intersection with $y$ axis. And notice that slope of a line is always constant so slopes of $t_f, t_g$ are $f'(a), g'(a).$ We have $\frac{f}{g}$. So If we divide numerator and denominator with same value it is impossible to have slopes or both $f, g$ because $x_f \neq x_g$.

Comment: That's why must be $f(a) = g(a).$ Another thing: we suppose that $g'(a) \neq 0$ because then $g$ would aproximatelly be (in the interval $a, a + dx$) just line $y = c, c \in \mathbb{R}$ so $\Delta{g} = 0$ and we would have $\frac{f}{0}$.

Comment: And yes only exceptions on rule "only when $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$" are those where limit is in form $\frac{c}{c},$ $c \in \mathbb{R}, 0 \neq c \neq \pm \infty$ and slopes of $t_f, t_g$ are equal - then they intersect in some point $(x, c)$ and have same slopes - so they are equal and then of course $x_f = x_g$ and we can apply L'Hopital's rule.                                                        Also, I think that your last example is wrong because $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin{x} = 0 \neq \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 + 1 = 1$ so you can't apply L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: The geometric intuition is good. And yes you're certainly right about the last example, sorry for that. A better example would be $(x+\sin x)/x$, which has limit $1$ as $x\to\infty$, but upon applying L'Hôpital's rule you obtain $1+\cos(x)$, for which the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! I think that this and simillar topics requires deep geometric understanding. Of course, formal proof is necessary, but I like analogy of the path and understanding; geometry or intuition is the winding path before complete understanding. Then, formalism is just like saying: done! So, thank you again.

Answer (score 10):

1.: The rule can also be applied in the case of $\frac{a}{\infty}$ and even when the limit of $f$ does not exist (but the limit of $g$ is $\infty$); but it's rarely told. To see why does it fail otherwise, you need to look at the proof. The most general case, when $g \to \infty$ can be proven with the Mean Value theorem and Stolz-Cesaro theorem and the $\frac{0}{0}$ is a consequence of this case. The problem comes from the Stolz-Cesaro theorem: the theorem requires the denominator to diverge to infinity.

2.: As I pointed it out on 1., they don't need to be zero; just their limits need to be "critical", i.e. $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or just $g\to \infty$.

3.: The proper requirement is $g' \neq 0$ around $a$. This is needed because the Mean Value Theorem would not be applicable in the proof otherwise.

4.: No, condition 3 does not imply that.

Comment: (+1) for your mentioning that it is not necessary that $f\to\infty$.  In fact, $\lim f$ need not even exist.  So the limit you have of $f\to a$ can be relaxed.  You might consider mentioning this.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, I missed it out. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This version of L'Hopital's Rule (where it is not assume that $f(x) \to \infty$) is proved in baby Rudin. **It is very surprising that not many students look at this theorem even though the book is so popular**.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: most students rarely look at exact hypotheses of various theorems and are interested only in conclusions

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Considering that there is no need to apply L'Hospital rule in that case (the limit has to be 0), this doesn't surprise me at all. That the rule still works is a nice theoretical tidbit, but it is useless knowledge for the calculations the students are asked to perform in the corresponding exam.

Comment: @mlk You are making a serious mistake. $f(x) $ not tending to $\infty$ does not mean that it remains  bounded. It can tend to  $\infty$ along some sequences and even tend to $0$ along others. The general version in Rudin's book is extremely useful and it is non-triivial.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've seen this fact being missed out by some high reputation user as well.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I should have been more precise there. I was refering to the case where a limit exists, which is the one suggested to me by $\frac{a}{\infty}$. The limitless case is theoretically interesting but putting it into an exam (without specifically covering it in class) would be a recipe for disaster. As there is normally never enough time to cover such special cases, no student needs it and thus no student will bother to learn it.

Comment: @mlk On MSE  have seen dozens of questions where Rudin's form of L'Hopital's Rule have been used. It has practical use I would encourage students to learn it.